# what are the compiler options for gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8-2014.04_linux?

Tags: gcc, armcc

I was using the options:

```
-O3
-march=armv7-a
-mtune=cortex-a8
-ftree-vectorize
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-fsigned-char
-Wall
-save-temps
```

for cross compiling for arm-v7 (32 bit) using ArmLinuxToolChain.

What is the equivalent compiler options for `gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8-2014.04_linux to build for armv8`? I tried using those same options  with -march=armv8-a
    -mtune=cortex-a53 and got:

> aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfloat-abi=softfp'

Comment: "but it's not working" is a hideously bad problem report :-) What are you actually seeing out of the compiler?

Comment: actual error messege is : aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command line option â-mfloat-abi=softfpâ

Comment: I'd start by trying _without_ that option. `softfp` is just software based floating point support and you may find it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The GCC options beginning with -m are machine-dependent options, so the availability of -m* options varies between targets. This is one such case. There is no soft float ABI defined for Aarch64, so GCC does not provide the ARM-specific `-mfloat-abi` option.

If you simply remove `-mfloat-abi=softfp` then your problem should be solved.

I would suggest you investigate whether you need `-save-temps`, which is normally only used for debugging or reporting compiler problems.